# I want to achieve flexible column selection in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have written the following code with the help of AI, but it's unable to perform a query for specific columns. The crucial part of the calling code is as follows:

action(struts2 code):

```
public String getBeanList() {
        SysMenuMapper mapper = SpringUtil.getBean(SysMenuMapper.class);
        SysMenuExample example = new SysMenuExample();
        Criteria c = example.createCriteria();
        c.andCondition(getConditions());
        Specification<SysMenu> where = c.getWhere();
        PageRequest pageReq = c.getPage();
        Page<SysMenu> page = mapper.findAll(where, pageReq);

        setResult(R.success(page.getContent(), page.getTotalElements()));
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

SysMenuMapper

```
@Repository
public interface SysMenuMapper extends  JpaRepository<SysMenu, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SysMenu> {

}
```

SysMenuExample looks like the code generated by MybatisGenerator

```
public static class Criteria extends GeneratedCriteria {
        protected Criteria() {
        }
    }

    public static class GeneratedCriteria implements JPAQuery<SysMenu> {
        private Specification<SysMenu> where;

        private List<Order> orderList;

        private Integer pn;

        private Integer pz;

        protected GeneratedCriteria() {
            where = Specification.where(null);
            orderList = new ArrayList<>();
            pn = 0;
            pz = 10;
        }

        private Criteria setPageParam(SearchCondition c, String fieldName) {
            List<Integer> pnVals = getValueByCondtion(c, fieldName, EQUAL_TO, Integer.class);
            if (!pnVals.isEmpty()) {
                Integer num = pnVals.get(0);
                Integer pageNumber = (num != null && num > 0) ? num - 1 : 0;
                Integer pageSize = (num != null && num > 0) ? num : 10;
                if (fieldName.equals(PN)) {
                    this.pn = pageNumber;
                } else {
                    this.pz = pageSize;
                }
            }
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        private Criteria setOrderBy(SearchCondition c) {
            String fieldName = c.getFieldName();
            List<String> values = getValueByCondtion(c, fieldName, ORDER_BY, String.class);
            if (Column.getFieldColumnInfo().containsKey(fieldName) && !values.isEmpty()) {
                if (StringUtils.equals("asc", values.get(0))) {
                    return ascBy(fieldName);
                } else if (StringUtils.equals("desc", values.get(0))) {
                    return descBy(fieldName);
                }
            }
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        private void setColumnNames(SearchCondition c) {
            List<Object> vals = c.getValues();
            if (vals != null && !vals.isEmpty()) {
                List<String> cols = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Object o : vals) {
                    if (o instanceof String && Column.getFieldColumnInfo().containsKey(o)) {
                        cols.add((String) o);
                    }
                }
                where = selectColumns(cols.toArray(new String[0]));
            }
        }

        public Criteria andCondition(List<SearchCondition> conditions) {
            List<SearchCondition> newCondition = new ArrayList<>(conditions);
            for (SearchCondition c : newCondition) {
                if (c != null) {
                    if (StringUtils.equals(COLUMN_NAMES, c.getFieldName())
                            && StringUtils.equals(IN, c.getCondition())) {
                        setColumnNames(c);
                    } else if (StringUtils.equals(PN, c.getFieldName())
                            && StringUtils.equals(EQUAL_TO, c.getCondition())) {
                        setPageParam(c, PN);
                    } else if (StringUtils.equals(PZ, c.getFieldName())
                            && StringUtils.equals(EQUAL_TO, c.getCondition())) {
                        setPageParam(c, PZ);
                    } else if (StringUtils.equals(ORDER_BY, c.getCondition())) {
                        setOrderBy(c);
                    } else if (Column.getFieldColumnInfo().containsKey(c.getFieldName())) {
                        Class<?> type = Column.getFieldTypeInfo().get(c.getFieldName());
                        c.setValues(ConvertUtil.convert(type, c.getValues()));
                        where = applyCondition(where, c);
                    }
                }
            }
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andCondition(SearchCondition... conditions) {
            return andCondition(Arrays.asList(conditions));
        }

        public Criteria ascBy(String... propertys) {
            if (propertys != null) {
                for (String property : propertys) {
                    orderList.add(Order.asc(property));
                }
            }
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria descBy(String... propertys) {
            if (propertys != null) {
                for (String property : propertys) {
                    orderList.add(Order.desc(property));
                }
            }
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria page(Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize) {
            pageNumber = (pageNumber != null && pageNumber > 0) ? pageNumber - 1 : 0;
            pageSize = (pageSize != null && pageSize > 0) ? pageSize : 10;
            this.pn = pageNumber;
            this.pz = pageSize;
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public PageRequest getPage() {
            if (orderList != null && !orderList.isEmpty()) {
                return PageRequest.of(pn, pz, Sort.by(orderList));
            } else {
                return PageRequest.of(pn, pz);
            }
        }

        public Specification<SysMenu> getWhere() {
            return where;
        }
```

JPAQuery code：

```
public interface JPAQuery<T> {

    default Specification<T> equalTo(String fieldName, Object value) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(getField(root, fieldName), value);
    }

    default Specification<T> notEqualTo(String fieldName, Object value) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.notEqual(getField(root, fieldName), value);
    }

    default Specification<T> isNull(String fieldName) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.isNull(getField(root, fieldName));
    }

    default Specification<T> selectColumns(String... fieldNames) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Selection<?>[] sections = getSelections(criteriaBuilder, root, fieldNames);
            query.multiselect(sections).distinct(true); // Here you need to clearly specify the fields to be queried
            return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
        };
    }

    default Selection<?>[] getSelections(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<T> root, String... fieldNames) {
        Selection<?>[] selections = new Selection[fieldNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
            selections[i] = root.get(fieldNames[i]);
        }
        return selections;
    }
}
```

I tried many ways to ask the AI for help, but the AI was helpless.
I want to pass column name parameters through the front end to realize which column names are passed by the front end and which fields are queried by the back end. For example, the front end passes the following parameters:

```
{
    "conditions": [
        {
            "fieldName": "columnNames",
            "condition": "In",
            "values": [
                "id"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The expected result is:

```
{
    "msg": "success",
    "result": {
        "count": 2,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "111"
            },
            {
                "id": "112"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```